# html5 video (mp4 & ogg) is not working with meteor on apache2 / phusion passenger

Tags: html, apache, video, meteor, passenger

Html5 video (mp4 & ogg) is not recognized from a meteor app on apache2 / phusion-passenger.

Apache mime types are configured.

Passenger mime types for mp4 and ogg are added:

```
video/mp4 mp4; 
video/ogg ogg ogv;
```

I always get the following message in firebug:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource myvideo.mp4 failed.
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource myvideo.ogg failed.
```

How can I fix this? Could it be a meteor problem ?

Comment: Then it seems the mime types aren't configured correctly?

Comment: the apache mime types are definitely correct. the passenger mime types for ogg and mp4 are not included in the standards and i added them: video/mp4   mp4; video/ogg   ogg ogv;

Comment: And they are actually being sent for the resource? That doesn't seem likely if the browser is claiming it's `text/html`, no?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer and it's a little bit strange...
in this case (meteor/apache/passenger) the mimetype of a video is needed to be  in uppercase.

```
<video ...>
    <source src="/video/myvideo.MP4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/video/myvideo.OGG" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

myvideo.MP4 and not myvideo.mp4.